# Limit the number of successful logins

Tags: php, shortcode, user-meta

I would like to retrieve the number of successful logins of a user and act accordingly.

If user logged in more than 10 times, then log out user automatically with wp_logout() or similar.

I would like to use the [Shortcode Exec PHP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-exec-php/) to execute the script in a page.

I have found this plugin [Simple Login Log](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-login-log/screenshots/), which could be useful for getting data from.

I don't know how to access the database to get data from it. The only way I can find is to set restrictions via the parameters that i set to post from a page, i.e. `http://www.domain.com/profiling?logins=%%current_user_logins%%`

then retrieve that parameter via PHP form

`http://www.domain.com/profiling?logins=1`

then if the parameter `logins` is more than 1, logout user with wp_logout();

the problem with this approach is that the user can manually modify the parameter and gain access.

Comment: Why do you want to use the `Shortcode Exec PHP` plugin?

Comment: @czerspalace because is a good way to use PHP. i am open to other ways to achieve the scope

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck? Do not expect the work to be done for you. Please update your question with an [edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/184841/edit). See [ask].

Comment: I don't know how to access the database to get data from it. The only way I can find is to set restrictions via the parameters that i set to post from a page, i.e. http://www.domain.com/profiling?l=%%current_user_level%%&a=%%current_user_logins%%

then retrieve that parameter via PHP, then logout user with wp_logout(); if %%current_user_logins%% is more than 1.

Comment: To access the db, you may want to look at [the wpdb class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb). You will also want to look into [WordPress hooks, most likely an add_action hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)

Comment: are you saying that accessing the DB to get this information is a better approach?

Comment: I personally think the best approach would be to store the data using [user meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta)

Comment: i just can't find anywhere how to count the logins of a user. is this too much to ask @Gabriel?